# C++ OpenGL - Colours

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to draw an 8-bit style games character (link from Zelda) as i'm practicing OpenGL.
I've started with his face, which is the big square to the right, and have drawn his eye which is two blocks to the right of the start of his face... (6 blocks, the 2 left most is an eye)

The top of the eye (the block above the green block) should be dark green (see code) but it keeps adopting the colour of the first larger block (the face).

I hope this makes sense...
Please see this picture:
[image: 8-Bit Char]

What am i doing wrong for it to keep changing its colour?

I'm assuming i need to do something more for it to accept RGB colours? `glColor3f(29, 137, 59);`...

Comment: Textures would be probably easier to work with.

Comment: Please don't use Immediate mode (glBegin, glEnd). Use vertex arrays. Those have been around for almost 20 years. However textures in GL_NEAREST filtering mode are probably much easier to work with.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`glColor3f` accepts a floating point argument. By doing this, the large numbers will be cast to floats, and therefore become 29.0f, 137.0f and 59.0f. Given colours are represented in the range of 0-1, these get clamped to the range 0-1 and of course, appear white (1.0, 1.0, 1.0).

Use `glColor3ub` instead. It accepts an unsigned byte as its argument, which is in the range of 0-255, which is probably what you're most used to. There's other forms such as `glColor3i`, `glColor3s`, `glColor3ui`, `glColor3us` etc which accept integers and shorts (and their unsigned variants) which are defined over the range of integers and shorts. These simply get converted to the decimal variant internally (e.g. `decimal = int / INT_MAX`).